# How to write java map to csv with jackson?

Tags: csv, jackson

I am using jackson-dataformat-csv.

I have a pojo which contains a java.util.Map. I know jackson does not support writing a map to csv directly, but is there any workaround? Basically i have semi-random key-value pairs which i need to write to csv. Can i do it manually somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

I've also looked and can't find anything. It's too bad, too, since it would be trivial to do the equivalent of flattening out the map and bringing it up to the top level.

Optionally, it could prefix the name of the map (specified by @JsonProperty) to prevent heading name collisions.

So a class with these members: 
`@JsonProperty("Name") String firstColumn = "Bart";
@JsonProperty("FamilyMember") Map family = ImmutableMap.of(
        "Dad", "Homer",
        "Mom", "Marge");`

could output like:

`Name,  FamilyMember.Dad,  FamilyMember.Mom
Bart,  Homer,             Marge`

Someone (@taivo) should contribute that!

But if you don't have time, you are probably better off just writing your own mapper to flatten the map into a pojo..